# What is CHUIIREDACTED?

Tags: utm

I got problem with utm tracking. 9/10 of following a link is ok but sometime this happend:
https://sitename.com/ad/party/?utm_source=CHUIIREDACTED&utm_medium=CHUIIREDACTED&utm_term=CHUIIREDACTED&utm_campaign=CHUIIREDACTED&utm_content=CHUIIREDACTED

So it is a big problem for me, because i cant track some orders. 
If anybody got answere to this question, i would thank you for that.

Comment: Your link results to 404. It's absolutely unclear what is the problem. Please be more specific.

Comment: its not a problem on a site, its problem with order utm track. I can give you link to the site, but problem doesnt affect the site work.
https://foodcult24.ru/ad/party/?utm_source=CHUIIREDACTED&utm_medium=CHUIIREDACTED&utm_term=CHUIIREDACTED&utm_campaign=CHUIIREDACTED&utm_content=CHUIIREDACTED

Comment: somehow on a user site utm parameter become CHUIIREDACTED

Comment: I don't think you can receive any help here at StackOverflow since your issue is not related to programming (and StackOverflow is for **that sort** of questions) but related to specific internal site settings. You should contact their (foodcult24.ru) support team

Comment: we are creators of the site and we did a lot parameters for all of products like {"name":"canapeSet"}
but we didnt added CHUIIREDACTED parameter so it appears from nowhere and it track random orders and products.
anyway thx for help

Comment: that's strange. If you manage to solve this, please share the solution with StackOverflow community

Comment: @eaistosystems I've got the same problem - `https://www.sitename.com/thanks/?o=CHUIIREDACTED&key=CHUIIREDACTED&type=CHUIIREDACTED`, did you get to the bottom of it?

Comment: I got similar, from strange UserAgent `facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)`, maybe some bots trying to scrap the site, without effecting real marketing data.

Comment: I got the same problem too!!! My page's query parameters were replaced by CHUIIREDACTED and hit continuously. Did anyone get to the bottom of it?